# Why does Netplan 104 not like configuration that works with 101?

Tags: 20.04, netplan

I have two systems running Ubuntu 20.04.

```
crs_admin@TST-CLD-vBWM01:~$ uname -a
Linux TST-CLD-vBWM01 5.4.0-94-generic #106-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 6 23:58:14 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
crs_admin@TST-CLD-vBWM01:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

I'm trying to configure them with netplan.  There is a `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` which configures one interface and an 05-* file which configures another.  (There are no `.yaml` files in `/lib/netplan/` or `/run/netplan/`.)

The "shape" of these two files is identical on the two systems; only the interface names and IP addresses are different.  (`file` says they are ASCII text, `ls -l` says they have the same number of bytes, and I have pulled them to a third system and done a character-by-character comparison.)

00 file:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    ens161:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.35.76/24
      gateway4: 192.168.35.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 10.145.100.5
        - 10.145.100.7
        - 8.8.8.8
        search:
        - mydomain.com
  version: 2
```

05 file:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160f0:
      addresses: [192.168.250.46/30]
      routes:
        - to: 10.110.0.0/15
          via: 192.168.250.45
    ens224f1:
      addresses: [192.168.250.50/30]
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 192.168.250.49
  version: 2
```

One of the systems is running Netplan 101:

```
$ sudo apt list --installed | grep netpl

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libnetplan0/now 0.101-0ubuntu3~20.04.2 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 0.104-0ubuntu2~20.04.2]
netplan.io/now 0.101-0ubuntu3~20.04.2 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 0.104-0ubuntu2~20.04.2]
```

This system works as expected.  Specifically, `netplan generate` does not give any warnings and I can ping the "via" addresses.

The other system is running 104:

```
$ sudo apt list --installed | grep netpl

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libnetplan0/focal-updates,now 0.104-0ubuntu2~20.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
netplan.io/focal-updates,now 0.104-0ubuntu2~20.04.2 amd64 [installed]
```

This system does *not* work as expected/desired.

First, `netplan generate` says:

> ** (generate:23145): WARNING **: 17:18:13.317: Problem encountered while validating default route consistency.Please set up multiple routing tables and use `routing-policy` instead.
> Error: Conflicting default route declarations for IPv4 (table: main, metric: default), first declared in ens224f1 but also in ens161

But there is no default route for ens161.

And if I press on despite the warning, I can ping out the `ens224f1` to 192.168.250.49 but I *cannot* ping out `ens160f0` to 192.168.250.45.

I'd be OK with downgrading to 101 if that solved the problem but when I look for available versions I find only 99 and 104.

Any insight is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Firstly, `gateway4` is deprecated.  Secondly you have **two default routes** defined, and you cannot do that.  You need to choose an interface to be your default unless you set up routing policy rules.  This isn't an issue due to *upgrading* or *downgrading* netplan,, but poor configuration on your part because you have two default routes specified and can only have one without advanced routing policies.

Comment: Thomas Ward, `gateway4` came from the installer.  I don't mind changing it but I didn't create it.

Also, I don't see two default routes.  I have 4 decades of development experience but `netplan` is not my specialty. I'm eager to learn.  What am I missing here?  Finally, if I do have two default routes, why does it work just fine on one system and not on the other?

Comment: They changed the syntax IIRC - with things in the backend changing

Comment: user535733, why does the netplan version predating the OS version raise a concern?  Surely 20.04 couldn't include (out of the box), netplan versions that ''postdated'' it.  (Neither system is stock, original 20.04.  I'm sure various updates have been applied inconsistently between them, clearly netplan at least.)

Comment: Each YAML file is creating a default route. In the first file with `gateway4: 192.168.35.1` and in the 2nd with `routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 192.168.250.49`. Look at output of `ip route`.

Comment: @ChrisNelson you're right; I was mistaken about the initial version. However, running 101 instead of 104 is curious. If regular upgrades are blocked, then perhaps security upgrades are blocked too. A different problem to look into.

Answer (score 0):

`gateway4` declares a default route; that's what a gateway is.  Thus you have two default routes declared on two different interfaces, and netplan now informs you that this is an incoherent configuration.

Comment: Cool.  Thanks. for the explanation (which mpboden also gave, above).  So my problem doesn't seem to be the different netplan versions but neither does it seem to be the netplan configuration because it works on one system and not on the other. :-(

Comment: Except it is due to the newer version of netplan, which now gives an error instead of letting you define a routing table which is technically valid but doesn't make sense.  You should work out where you actually want default traffic to the Internet to go, and that's the default route you should keep. If you want different traffic to use different routes, that's when you need routing tables, as the error message says.